# Is there an update only mode for Windows?

Tags: windows-server-2016, virtualbox

I have a windows virtual machine (VirtualBox) that I reset to a snapshot on an hourly basis.

The purpose is to provide a safe & consistent internet accessible DEMO / Test environment.

On an irregular basis I manually install all available windows updates and save a new Snapshot.

I would like to create a process where the Windows 2016 VM either: **a) launches as,** or **b) switches to,** a mode where it blocks all access attempts and enters a SAFE mode of sorts where all it can do is download and apply Microsoft updates.

- Is there such a mode?
- Is Safe Mode what I am looking for?
- Is there another alternative that I am unaware of?
- How can I initiate this when starting the VM?
- Alternately, how can I initiate this within a user session?

My objective is to create a process where a internet connected Virtual machine running Windows 2016 can safely update itself without the risk that someone or something else might make an unexpected update.

Once the updates are complete then a new snapshot will be taken.

Answer (score 1):

My solution which is a work in progress is a simple script that shuts down services such as IIS and then runs wuauclt to get windows to get the updates and shutdown.

```
iisreset /stop
net stop W3SVC
net stop MSSQL$SQLEXPRESS
net stop OracleServiceXE
net stop MySQL57
net stop Server

wuauclt /detectnow /updatenow && shutdown /s /t 0
```